# Worklight Loading Indicator

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, ibm-mobilefirst

Our applications loading process is lengthy, so to provide the user with indication the app is functioning and merely loading, we want to provide a loading/initializing indicator.  I tried using WL's busy indicator, but it seems its availability isn't complete this early in the apps lifecycle.  So I just created a simple DIV in our single-page application with loading indication.  Once the app has completed loading, I just hide it.  It works fine when I first run the app.  Future runs behave differently.

**First Run**: It shows up immediately and is hidden once the app has finished its initialization.
**Subsequent runs**: It doesn't show up with the first presentation and flashes quickly just before the app completes initialization and begins normal flow.

**The loading DIV** (I made this completely static and not dependent on any JS or CSS):

```
    <div id="loadingInd"
         style="z-index:1;position:absolute;left:85px;top:185px;display:block;">
         Loading2...
    </div>
```

**Hiding code**:

```
    $('#loadingInd').hide()
```

A little info on the loading process:

We pre-load all JS and HTML files used by the application.  A task to change this to a more lazy loading process is in the works, but hasn't moved high enough the priority list to be completed.  Once all JS and HTML files are loaded, we present UI widgets (menu, login button, etc).  Until the loading is complete we just have a loading splashscreen.  So that loadingInd DIV is just static content in the splashscreen.  What I don't understand is why it shows up immediately with the rest of the splashscreen when the app is first run, but doesn't show up till much later in subsequent runs.  I think the reason it looks like it's flashing is because it's getting drawn just before the call to hide().  Is there something about subsequent runs that might cause this different drawing behavior?  I've logged CSS info in multiple places along the initialization process and everything seems consistent among first and subsequent loads.

---

After a bit of discussion here, I've gone back to trying the busyIndicator.  I show it just before I start loading all my content and hide it when I'm ready to start loading widgets.  It behaves just like the DIV from above.  I'm thinking there's something going on with the drawing.

Comment: Something's missing... this is Worklight WL.BusyIndicator API? Where do you initialize it? I think it would be more beneficial if you add more code snippets... where you're calling it, where you're hiding it, ...

Comment: I tried using WL.BusyIndicator API by initializing it in my initOptions.js.  initOptions.js is the first JS file included in my HTML file.  Other than sharing my whole app, I don't know what other code snippets would be considered relevant.  I can surely share something if you can direct me accordingly.

Comment: As per when I'm calling it and when I'm hiding it.  I call it just before I enter my for loop to load all my HTML files and I hide it just when I start presenting my UI widgets.  There are no additional WL loads, to my knowledge, after I show() it.  Regardless, I'm not using it anymore.  I'm using a simple DIV that says "Loading".

Comment: I don't understand, you are initing the busyindicator in inioptions.js? This should be done in wlcommoninit() AFAIK.

Comment: Ahh, my fault. it is.  In any case, I'm not using busyIndicator.

Comment: Okay, so just to wrap it, you've basically created some div that you display it during "load" and hide it afterwards, using your own custom JS

Comment: Yes, and to be clear, I don't explicitly display it.  It's part of the static content in my app's HTML page.  It's a single page app.  I've tried calling .show() on the DIV to explicitly show it, but it didn't have any effect.

Comment: So I'm just wondering, again, why do you not use WL.BusyIndicator? do a busy.show() when the app content is loading and a busy.hide() when the content is done loading... just initialize it correctly. var busy; before wlCommonInit() and busy = new WL.BusyIndicator(); in it, and then just busy.show() / busy.hide() where required.

Comment: Just tried it.  It exhibits the same behavior.  Works as intended the first time.  When I force close the app and start it anew, I see my logging lines go by indicating I've shown the busyIndicator and the indicator isn't up.  A few seconds later, it flashes quickly and the widgets load.

Comment: Is this Worklight 5.0.5.x, 5.0.6.x or 6.0?

Comment: Also - would be interesting if you can reproduce this in a new app as well, or a small test case app.

Comment: 5.0.5.x.  I'm working on a new test app atm now, actually.

Comment: Do you quit the app and start it again, or do you move it to the background and then bring it to the foreground? In other words, do you tap the back button or the home button before starting the app for a second run? This happens on Android, yes?

Comment: I quit the app, I don't just background it.  I haven't tried it on Android, I think that's something I need to try.  Though I can't try it today cause I don't have access to one today.  First thing tomorrow.

Comment: any change in respect to this question?

Comment: hey @dharga I added a jsfiddle could you please check if it is suitable for you?

Answer (score 0):

I used this on my website, edit: here is a link to a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sYghV/4/

```
$(window).load(function() {
$("#pageLoadingMessage").fadeTo("fast", 0, function() {
      document.getElementById("pageLoadingMessage").style.zIndex="-100";
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="pageLoadingMessage"> 
<p style="top: 50%; position: absolute; left: 50%;">
<img src="http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
</p> 
</div>
```

css:

```
#pageLoadingMessage {
background-color: gray;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 100;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```